What happens when a magnetic monopole is placed in a spherical superconducting shell?
According to the Meissner effect, a superconducting material expels all magnetic field inside it. But if we placed a magnetic charge inside a spherical superconducting shell $S$, it would be impossible to prevent some magnetic flux from going through the shell, by Gauss's law. So what happens?
If we try to use the London equations, $\nabla \times \mathbf{J} \propto \mathbf{B}$, then we get a contradiction, because
$$q_M = \int_S \mathbf{B} \cdot d \mathbf{S} \propto \int_S (\nabla \times \mathbf{J}) \cdot d \mathbf{S} = 0$$
by Stokes' theorem, since the sphere has no boundary. So the London equations must break down.
By spherical symmetry, we might expect that the material does nothing at all, $\mathbf{J} = 0$, so that a magnetic field simply goes through the superconductor. This doesn't seem right though. If the shell was very large, how would each piece of it "know" that it shouldn't do anything, because it's actually part of a closed shell? It seems something must happen, at least initially.
Perhaps some kind of symmetry breaking occurs, where the shell sets up screening currents so that all the magnetic flux is funneled out of one small part of the shell, which becomes non-superconducting. But then what determines the dynamics of this process? Do we get only one non-superconducting part, or several, or many?

I will focus only on the bulk effect, so I will assume that the shell is very thick compared to all characteristic lengthscales. Equivalently, this is the same as studying 2D superconductivity on a sphere. I will also assume the monopole's charge to be sufficiently small so that the applied external magnetic field is lower than the critical field, or else the entire sphere is in the normal phase.
Type I
Since there is a net magnetic flux, the sphere cannot be entirely in the superconducting state. Some of it must be in the normal state where the flux will pass through even if the magnetic field is below the critical value. You will therefore obtain a coexistence of phases. To understand the organisation of the phases, you need to compare the three relevant length scales of the system: $R$ the radius of the sphere, $\xi$ the coherence length of the superconductor and $\lambda$ the London penetration length.
For an extreme type I superconductor, the London's equations do not hold because $\xi \gg \lambda$. Below the critical field, the normal phase and superconducting phase will clump into two separate domains. You will get the spherical analogue of the superfluid vortex. Since the size of the vortex is given by $\xi$, if $\xi\gg R$, your sphere still essentially covered by the normal phase. As $\xi$ is smaller with respect to $R$, the vortex gets more and more localised. At the centre of the vortex, you will have a small core where the magnetic field is not zero through which all the flux will pass through.
You may remember that the circulation of vortex is quantised. This is consistent with the charge quantisation of magnetic charges, so that it is possible for all the flux to escape through the vortex.
Quantitatively, the vortex will have rotation symmetry, so in the appropriate spherical coordinates $\theta,\phi$ you have $\psi(\theta),A_\phi(\theta),B_r(\theta)$:
$$
\frac1{R^2\sin\theta}(\sin\theta\psi')'+\frac1{\lambda^2}A_\phi^2\psi+\frac1{\xi^2}(|\psi|^2-1)\psi = 0 \\
B_r = \frac1{R\sin\theta}(\sin\theta A_\phi)' \\
-\frac1RB_r' = -\frac1{\lambda^2}|\psi|^2A_\phi
$$
For an extreme type I superconductor, $\xi \gg \lambda$, so for a vortex of circulation $n$, the equations effectively decouple:
$$
\frac1{R^2\sin\theta}(\sin\theta\psi')'+\frac{n^2}{R^2\sin^2\theta}\psi+\frac1{\xi^2}(|\psi|^2-1)\psi = 0
$$
for the superfluid vortex.
Type II
For very small charge, you are again in the Meissner phase, so you have the same picture as before. You have one large vortex, this time described by the London equation:
$$
-\frac1{R^2\sin\theta}(\sin\theta B_r') = -\frac1{\lambda^2}B_r
$$
with a small normal phase core.
However, in the vortex phase between the two critical values of external field, the picture changes. It is not favourable anymore to have a single vortex, but rather to break it up into many individual vortices. You would therefore expect a lattice of such vortices distributed more or less uniformly over the sphere.
This is consistent with your intuition in the third paragraph. Say you remove the monopoles at the origin and at infinity and instead add an annulus of current sheet along the equatorial plane. The superconducting region at the pole will see almost no difference in the external applied field. You therefore expect the same results as for thin film superconductors under a magnetic field.
You need to be careful with symmetry argument because while the setup is spherically symmetric, the individual solutions need not be spherically symmetric. It only means that a rotated solution is again a solution, but without uniqueness, you do not necessarily recover the original solution. In fact, in this case, you have a degeneracy of solutions, consistent with the fact that individual solutions break rotational invariance.
Actually, even with the linear case with no superconductivity, you have a similar effect. Thinking in terms of the vector potential, you need to create a singularity on the sphere, like a point where the Dirac string can pierce through. With superconductivity, the Dirac string acquires a physical "body" via the vortex, and is not just a gauge dependent artefact anymore.

Thanks, this is very enlightening. Could you elaborate on the case of type I superconductors? I wasn't aware that the London equation only applied to type II.
